# Use of unresolved identifier 'SyncCredentials'

Tags: swift, mongodb, realm

i am new to realm and ios development. I was following realm tutorial for build a full sync app on their website
https://docs.realm.io/sync/getting-started-1/step-1-my-first-realm-app.

The app keep showing this error

> Use of unresolved identifier 'SyncCredentials'

here is my code

```js
import RealmSwift

@objc func signIn() {
    logIn(username: username!, password: password!, register: false)
}

@objc func signUp() {
    logIn(username: username!, password: password!, register: true)
}

// Log in with the username and password, optionally registering a user.
func logIn(username: String, password: String, register: Bool) {
    print("Log in as user: \(username) with register: \(register)");
    setLoading(true);
    let creds = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username: username, password: password, register: register);
    SyncUser.logIn(with: creds, server: Constants.AUTH_URL, onCompletion: { [weak self](user, err) in
        self!.setLoading(false);
        if let error = err { 
            // Auth error: user already exists? Try logging in as that user.
            print("Login failed: \(error)");
            self!.errorLabel.text = "Login failed: \(error.localizedDescription)"
            return;
        }
        print("Login succeeded!");
        self!.navigationController!.pushViewController(ItemsViewController(), animated: true);
    });
}
```

how can I fix this error?

Comment: Did you `import RealmSwift`?

Comment: @Frankenstein yes i did

Answer (score 0):

Your code is in the wrong place. All of the code in that example needs to fall within the UIViewController. So it would look like this

```
import RealmSwift

class WelcomeViewController: UIViewController {
    let usernameField = UITextField()
    let passwordField = UITextField()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad();
       view.backgroundColor = .white
       ...
    }

    @objc func signIn() {
       logIn(username: username!, password: password!, register: false)
    }

    @objc func signUp() {
       logIn(username: username!, password: password!, register: true)
    }

    func logIn(username: String, password: String, register: Bool) {
       print("Log in as user: \(username) with register: \(register)");
       setLoading(true);
       let creds = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username: username, password: password, register: register);
       ...
    }
```

Comment: this is what I tried. I double check my code with your answer and still got the same error. I dont know if SyncCredentials has been deprecated

Comment: @learner101 It doesn't appear to be what you've tried. If you look at the code in your question vs the code in my answer, you can see your question is missing the surrounding `class WelcomeViewController:` code. If you have that, please update the question with your actual code, if not, the code in my answer works as it was pulled from an existing project. Oh and no, SyncCredentials is not depreciated at this time - we use it all the time

Comment: I was able to fix it by removing and reinstalling RealmSwift. But I ran into another issue I posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62999928/realm-error-domain-io-realm-unknown-code-89-operation-canceled