# Realm Error Domain=io.realm.unknown Code=89 "Operation canceled"

Tags: swift, realm

I don't if this is a URL issue. Everything works fine but when trying to Async open the realm, I get a domain error.

My data is stored in a database Store.items. Here is my screen shot
[image]

I want to sync to server data to my local realm database.
here is my code

I have a Constants.swift file

```js
import Foundation
 
struct Constants {
    // **** Realm Cloud Users:
    // **** Replace MY_INSTANCE_ADDRESS with the hostname of your cloud instance
    // **** e.g., "mycoolapp.us1.cloud.realm.io"
    // ****
    // ****
    // **** ROS On-Premises Users
    // **** Replace the AUTH_URL string with the fully qualified versions of
    // **** address of your ROS server, e.g.: "http://127.0.0.1:9080"

    static let MY_INSTANCE_ADDRESS = "app.us1a.cloud.realm.io" // <- update this

  
    static let AUTH_URL  = URL(string: "https://\(MY_INSTANCE_ADDRESS)")!
    static let REALM_URL = URL(string: "realms://\(MY_INSTANCE_ADDRESS)/appName")!

    
    



}
```

```js
 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
        SyncServertoLocal()
        
        }


    @objc func SyncServertoLocal(){
        print("trying to sync")
        let config = SyncUser.current?.configuration(realmURL: Constants.REALM_URL, fullSynchronization: true)
              Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: config!) { realm, error in
                         if let realm = realm {
                             // Realm successfully opened, with all remote data available
                             print("Remote data available")
                             
                         } else if let error = error {
                             // Handle error that occurred while opening or downloading the contents of the Realm
                            
                            print("Opps we have a realm problem", error)
                            
                         }
                     }
              
    }
```

> Opps we have a realm problem Error Domain=io.realm.unknown Code=89 "Operation canceled" UserInfo={Category=realm.basic_system, NSLocalizedDescription=Operation canceled, Error Code=89}

it appears like no data is syncing but I don't know what the error means and how to fix it. How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you're mixing the existing Realm Sync documentation with the **BETA** MongoDB Realm Documentation - apparently a common issue.

The setup is different between the two and you cannot use the MongoDB Realm console to access your Realm Sync database - it can only be used with the **BETA** MongoDB Realm.

Here's the [MongoDB Realm Sync](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/sync-data/#ios-sync-data) docs noting that your objects need to have a partition key that matches the one set up on the console. Additionally, the connection sequence is different and looks more like this, including the partition and omitting fullSync (and others)

```
let user = app.currentUser()
let partitionValue = "myPartition"
Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: user.configuration(partitionValue: partitionValue),
```

The code in your question is for the 'classic' and current [Realm Sync](https://docs.realm.io/sync/). You can access your Realm Sync with the [Realm Studio](https://docs.realm.io/sync/realm-studio) app if you want to stick with the non-beta Realm.

Also note that working with objects is slightly different as well because you need to include the partition value for each object. For example, with MongoDB Realm, adding a task object would be this code

```
try! realm.write {
  realm.add(Task(partition: partitionValue, name: "My task"))
}
```

Whereas, with classic Realm its just

```
try! realm.write {
  realm.add(Task(name: "My task"))
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Realm documentation is so confusing and alot of times outdated.

Comment: @Jay I get the exact same problem but not with the same configuration, I filed a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63014699/operation-canceled-realm-error-domain-io-realm-unknown-code-89