# “Operation canceled” Realm Error Domain=io.realm.unknown Code=89

Tags: ios, swift, synchronization, realm

I get the exact same error as [#62999928](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62999928/realm-error-domain-io-realm-unknown-code-89-operation-canceled), but not with the same configuration. I'm just trying to access a global Realm file which is on my Realm Cloud (I am **NOT** on MongoDB and the beta).

I get the `“Operation canceled” Realm Error Domain=io.realm.unknown Code=89` error when I try to open the Realm.

Realm Studio:
[image]

Opening code:

```
let url = URL(string: "realms://\(MY_INSTANCE_ADDRESS)/common")!
let config = user.configuration(realmURL: url, fullSynchronization: true)

Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: config) { ... }
```

Authentication code (using PromiseKit):

```
private func connectToRealm(_ firebaseUser: User) -> Promise<SyncUser> {
    
    // if realm user already logged in, check if it's the right user
    if let user = SyncUser.current {
        guard user.identity == firebaseUser.uid else {
            // it's not the right user. log out and try again.
            user.logOut()
            return connectToRealm(firebaseUser)
        }
        
        // it's the right user.
        return Promise.value(user)
    }

    return firstly {
        // get JWT token with firebase function
        Promise {
            Functions.functions().httpsCallable("myAuthFunction").call(completion: $0.resolve)
        }
        
    }
    .compactMap { result in
        // extract JWT token from response
        return (result?.data as? [String: Any])?["token"] as? String
        
    }
    .then { token in
        // connect to Realm
        Promise {
            SyncUser.logIn(with: SyncCredentials.jwt(token), server:MY_AUTH_URL, onCompletion: $0.resolve)
        }
    }
}
```

This method is called after logging with Firebase. The auth URL is just `https://\(MY_INSTANCE_ADDRESS)`.

I suspect it's a permission problem, in which case: how can I easily let this file be readable by everyone, but not writable? I'm not planning on creating a lot of theses files, I just want to do this once.

**EDIT:** I reduced my code to the bare minimum.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    let MY_INSTANCE_ADDRESS = [...]
    let AUTH_URL = URL(string: "https://\(MY_INSTANCE_ADDRESS)")!
    let COMMON_REALM_URL = URL(string: "realms://\(MY_INSTANCE_ADDRESS)/common")!

    SyncUser.logIn(with: SyncCredentials.anonymous(), server: AUTH_URL) { (user, error) in
        guard error == nil && user != nil else {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        
        let config = user!.configuration(realmURL: COMMON_REALM_URL, fullSynchronization: true)
        Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: config) { (realm, error) in
            guard error == nil && realm != nil else {
                print(error)
                return
            }

            print("Successfully loaded Realm file with \(realm!.objects(MyObjectType.self).count) objects.")
            
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing else is running, I don't load my app window. Still getting the same error.

**EDIT 2**: changed code according to @Jay's comment.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    let MY_INSTANCE_ADDRESS = [...]
    let AUTH_URL = URL(string: "https://\(MY_INSTANCE_ADDRESS)")!
    let COMMON_REALM_URL = URL(string: "realms://\(MY_INSTANCE_ADDRESS)/common")!

    SyncUser.logIn(with: SyncCredentials.anonymous(), server: AUTH_URL) { (user, error) in
        guard error == nil && user != nil else {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        print("logged in")
        
        let config = SyncUser.current?.configuration(realmURL: COMMON_REALM_URL, fullSynchronization: true)
        
        let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config!)
        
        // $$$
        let objectsResult = realm.objects(MyObjectType.self)
        self.notificationToken = objectsResult.observe { changes in
            print("changes: \(changes)")

            if case .initial(let results) = changes {
                print("\(results.count) results: \(results)")
            }

        }
        // $$$
    }
}
```

Result:

```
logged in
changes: initial(Results<MyObjectType> <0x155d2d4e0> (

))
0 results: Results<MyObjectType> <0x155d2d4e0> (

)
```

No error, but I don't get the content that are on the cloud.

**EDIT 3** Okay that's interesting. By changing the code between the `$$$` to:

```
        try! realm.write {
            realm.create(MyObjectType.self, value: MyObjectType(id: 2021, name_fr: "test_fr", name_eng: "test_eng"))
        }
        
        let objectsResult = realm.objects(MyObjectType.self)
        print(objectsResult)
```

I get the result:

```
logged in
Results<MyObjectType> <0x143fe0510> (
    [0] MyObjectType {
        id = 2020;
        name_fr = test_fr;
        name_eng = test_eng;
    }
)
```

So the object is being written. When I run again the same code (without the login part) and changing the object id, I get:

```
Results<MyObjectType> <0x111d507c0> (
    [0] MyObjectType {
        id = 2020;
        name_fr = test_fr;
        name_eng = test_eng;
    },
    [1] MyObjectType {
        id = 2021;
        name_fr = test_fr;
        name_eng = test_eng;
    }
)
```

So the objects are stored somewhere. However, I don't see these two objects in Realm Studio. In Realm Studio, I see the objects that I added using a JS script, which should be downloaded to the device but are not.

When I run again the code after logging out, the objects are removed. All the URLs are correct, and I checked that no other Realm file is created by running the code.

Comment: Where is that sync code coming from? Take a look a the [Realm Sync Getting Started Guide](https://docs.realm.io/sync/getting-started-1/step-1-my-first-realm-app) section 6, and the code `func logIn(username` using SyncCredentials. Then take a look at [Full Sync Sample](https://docs.realm.io/sync/using-synced-realms/setting-up-your-realms#full-sync-realms-sample). It looks like you're using the code to open the default sync'd realm, which is not longer supported. ".. default synced Realm is only compatible with query-based sync, but query-based sync is no longer recommended... use Full sync."

Comment: @Jay I don't see which part of my code can be outdated, it's basically the same as on the second link you sent. I am not trying to synced with the default Realm, but with a Realm I created called "common", which is setup for full synchronization as you can see on my Realm Studio screenshot. I removed the PromiseKit code in my example to make it simpler.

Comment: Can you include your authenticate code in the question?

Comment: @Jay I added it. I can connect to the user realm without problem (`realms://\(MY_INSTANCE_ADDRESS)/~/myRealm`). I just have the problem with the common shared Realm.

Comment: Can you try opening it synchronously? Like this `let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)` and see if you get the same error or result?

Comment: Opening it synchronously does not throw any error, but the Realm returned is empty (in Realm Cloud, it's not), and it does not receive any change notification when I change the data in Realm Studio.

Comment: In fact, the same happen when I put a random url to a realm that doesn't exist, which means the app can't open the realm even though no error is thrown.

Comment: You won't receive any notification event of data changes unless you added a specific listener to a realm results object. This is all telling me there's an initial setup issue with sync. Any way you could just bypass the PromiseKit for now and just use straight Swift & Realm Sync calls?

Comment: @Jay I reduced my code to the bare minimum, see edit. Thank you for helping me...

Comment: Two things to try for testing purposes. 1) Log into the Realm Cloud portal an ensure Anonymous Login is Enabled - it is by default but check it. 2) instead of `let config = user!...` do this `let syncUserConfig = SyncUser.current?.configuration(realmURL: COMMON_REALM_URL, fullSynchronization: true)` and then don't do this `Realm.asyncOpen` but do this `let realm = try! Realm(configuration: syncUserConfig!)` and then try to load something from Realm. Let us know if there is any difference.

Comment: I changed the code as you said, see edit. I still don't get any result.

Comment: Interesting. Remove the notification code. Try writing a MyObjectType to realm. Then do this `let objectsResult = realm.objects(MyObjectType.self)` and then `print(objectsResult)` and see if it print the object you just wrote to console. Also, use RealmStudio and see if there are any objects in the common realm,

Comment: @Jay that's interesting, see edit. Objects seem to be stored per user, not globally. But the URL is correct and point to a `/common` Realm file.

Comment: The object creation code is odd. Take this out `realm.create(MyObjectType.self, value: MyObjectType(id: 2021, name_fr: "test_fr", name_eng: "test_eng"))` and replace it with two lines: `let x = MyObjectType(id: 2021, name_fr: "test_fr", name_eng: "test_eng")` and then `realm.add(x)` and try it again and report any differences.

Comment: @Jay tried it, no difference.

Comment: I posted some info over in the Realm forums but also, did you inspect the Logs? Make sure you Show levels is all so you can see all interactions.

Comment: @Jay I should have checked the logs sooner. I get `{"type":"https://docs.realm.io/server/troubleshoot/errors#access-denied","title":"The path is invalid or current user has no access.","status":403,"code":614}`, which confirms it's a permission problem (the path is definitely correct). It seems the top-level Realm are created with no permission access by default. How can I see/change the permission of my Realm file in Realm Studio? I want to allow everyone to read but not write this Realm.

Comment: Anonymous users have full access to Realm - and are really for testing and development purposes and not really designed for production. This doesn't appear to be a permission issue as yours are exactly the same as mine (no permissions); I can log in with username/pw with an existing admin user (in the Users tab in Realm Studio), or use anonymous login and have access to the same data. The only caveat is if you turned off anonymous access in the Realm Cloud website.

Comment: @Jay let's continue this discussion on [MongoDB forums](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/operation-canceled-realm-error-domain-io-realm-unknown-code-89/6967/9). Please see my comments there.